# How to use Kendo UI on Multi Select with Search using Post API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I have added Kendo UI on multi-select and use Post API to fetch the data on the basis of the search.
Here is the code in which I have tried to implement it.

```
var searchx = ""
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url : "https://searchapi/list",
            type: 'POST',
            data: function (params) {
                console.log("1");
                var searchTerm = params.term && params.term != "" ? params.term : searchx;
                var query = {
                                         "txt": [
                                                              {
                                                                   "txt: "Level4",
                                                                    "values": [
                                                                               "1819"
                                                                              ]
                                                              },
                                                              {
                                                                   "txt": "Level3",
                                                                   "values": []
                                                              },
                                                              {
                                                                   "txt": "Level2",
                                                                    "values": []
                                                              },
                                                              {
                                                                   "txt": "Leve1",
                                                                   "values": [
                                                                              "278"
                                                                             ]
                                                              }
                                                           ],
                                           "xyz": [
                                                              {
                                                                  "dt": "2022-04-24",
                                                                  "field": "startDate"
                                                              },
                                                              {
                                                                  "dt": "2022-05-24",
                                                                  "field": "endDate"
                                                              }
                                                           ],
                                            "sorts": [],
                                            "limit": 50,
                                            "q": searchTerm
                }
                searchx = searchTerm;                
                console.log("2");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(query));
                return JSON.stringify(query);
                //return Json(ds, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
            },
            datatype: "json",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                console.log('beforeSend');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer @Session.AuthToken~');
            }
        }
    },
    serverFiltering: true,
   serverSorting: true,
   placeholder: "Select One..."
});
$("#Tasks").kendoMultiSelect({
        placeholder: "Select Tasks...",
         filter: "contains",
        autoBind: false,
    dataValueField: "objectId",
    dataTextField : "title",
    dataSource : ds
});
```

Autocomplete / Typeahead search . I have created a Multi-select control by using kendo.The Multi-Select is not working Can anybody can help me with this

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Have you checked dev tools ? Is the request being opened? Is there an exception in the console? We need info or a demo, something to help you. Also, you have a typo in your code right here: `"txt: "Level4",`

Comment: I am not able to pass query string parameter in kendo

Comment: You can use a function in [`url`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.read#transport.read.url) parameter to concat your parameters to the url